# Python Numpy: How to create the following list of lists

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create the following list of list, in python (with Numpy or Pandas ideally):

`[[0,1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5]]`.

Anyone has an idea of a quick way to achive that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> [range(i,6) for i in range(6)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5], [5]]
```

As for doing it `numpy` or `pandas`, I am not familiar with any easy way of doing it, since the sublists are of different lengths.

Comment: Ok yes, I was thinking there was something to be done with diagonal array but your solution is perfect.

Comment: Yes, the pandas dataframe expects a table-like data structure, not this unbalanced list.  I'm familiar with numpy arrays but I think a simple python list works best.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a range list and simply slice to obtain each *sub-list*. The idea is to minimal work inside a loop comprehension for efficiency purposes.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
def reducing_ranges(n):
    r = range(n)
    return [r[i:] for i in r]
```

Sample run -

```
>>> reducing_ranges(6)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5], [5]]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [38]: %timeit [range(i,6) for i in range(6)] # @Akavall's soln
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.65 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit reducing_ranges(6)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 µs per loop

In [40]: %timeit [range(i,1000) for i in range(1000)] # @Akavall's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 9.96 ms per loop

In [41]: %timeit reducing_ranges(1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.96 ms per loop
```